# How to type some values for database table in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I downloaded source code of an `ASP.NET MVC` book and it looks this, I can see the table but I need to enter some data in it so it can show them to me 
Where should I go to enter data?

[image]

Comment: what about right click on the table, show data?

Comment: I did not see the snapshot before. Looks like you already have the data connection set. You can follow the instruction submitted as answer by me below. You should be able to see/update data by right clicking on the table and clicking on Show Table Data.

Answer (score 1):

While you should actually do this in SQL Server Management Studio, Visual Studio does offer you some support to deal with data. To do so, Open Server Explorer (Ctrl+Alt+S) in VS. Create a data connection, if it doesnt exist already to the DB in question by right clicking on Data Connection and click on Add Connection. Since you downloaded the source code for exercises, there is a good chance that they already created one for you. Once you have a connection to your desired database, you will be able to see database object under that including tables. To add data to a table, right click on that table and click on Show Table Data. You can then go to individual cells and enter data. Hitting enter should submit the data change to SQL Server.

Hope this helps..